# How to implement Partial Updates (PATCH) in Restful Web API (.NET/ JSON/ EF6) Server side

Tags: c#, json, rest, entity-framework-6, patch

I have been working on a Web API project (Restful), where the size of models (and respective table) is pretty huge, hence there is an absolute need of Partial Updates.

I have reviewed the option of POST to a subsection of the model, but given that the model has huge amount of fields (and custom fields), don't think it feasible to expose that many URIs).

I understand that using PATCH verb, I can allow a client to do partial updates, but I am struggling to conceptualize how should I capture the same on the server side and then find out what's changed (post JSON to model conversion) so that I can distinguish what field(s) are explicitly set as NULL by client (as she wanted to update field) Vs. what is NULL as a result of no update.

Should I use a custom mapper? or should I create generic properties and capture state at a field level?

I have searched (and still doing) net and here at SOF.com, but there is nothing authoritative/ concrete that I have found, so reaching out to pros for feedback.

appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

KevinDockx created plugin to MVC that handle PATCH. Here is nuget link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Marvin.JsonPatch/

This plugin is RFC 6902 implementation for .NET..

basically when you send json patch from your client you have to build array of operations

```
[
    { "op": "add", "path": "/foo", "value": "bar"},
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/baz", "value": "boo" }
]
```

Of course it only matters if you want to follow Specification. In other case (I mean your own understanding of how PATCH works) you have to implement your custom logic.

**EDIT**

Personally I found that only 'replace' operation was useful in my use-cases because of flat nature of my DTOs.